# Open Site Shell doesn't work with Local by Flywheel on Linux

Tags: wordpress

Installed `Local by Flywheel` on Garuda Linux running KDE Plasma. From the sites context menu the `Open Site Shell` command doesn't launch a shell.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, `Local` is using `gnome-terminal`. When `Open Site Shell` command is used, gnome-terminal is executed with a script as an argument. There are couple of ways this can be resolved:

1. Install `gnome-terminal` package.
2. Create a shell script `gnome-terminal` and put in a folder in your PATH.

Using the second option, my /usr/bin/gnome-terminal` contains:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

exec /usr/bin/konsole -e  "/bin/bash $@"
```